# How to get the device where some AD user locked his account in C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

How can I find out on which device an AD user locked his account? Sometimes a user is logged in to more than one device. So it is not easy to find out which device locks the account all the time.

I am already reading out the time, when the user locked his account. See below:

```
using (PrincipalContext pc_context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain", "someUser", "somePassword"))
{
    UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(pc_context);
    PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(user);
    user.SamAccountName = samAccountName;
    UserPrincipal resultUser = search.FindOne() as UserPrincipal;
}
```

And with this property:

```
resultUser.LastBadPasswordAttempt
```

I get the time the user locked his account. But how can I find out on which device that happened?

Comment: I don't think this information is retained by AD.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever how else can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's in the Event Viewer of the domain controller that locked out the account. Look in the Security events. You have the time it happened, so you can look for events at that time. The Event ID for locking out an account is 4740, so you can filter by that too.

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4740

If you have more than one domain controller for your domain, you will have to look at the events on each one.